# What is the meaning of non-integer powers of physical units in electrodynamics?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, metrology

In the [gaussian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) the unit of the charge is the statcoulomb (statC), defined as $$ \mathrm{statC =dyn^{1/2} cm= cm^{3/2} g^{1/2} s^{−1}}$$
to be consistent with the fact that the Coulomb force is measured in $\mathrm{g\,cm\, s^{-2}}$ without defining new fundamental units (the Ampère). So, in this non-standard units system is possible to have rational powers of physical units, but do they have a physical meaning on their own? Or is just a way to make the units consistent?

---

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175753/what-does-a-unit-like-c1-5-or-kg1-2-physically-mean) is related, but they are talking about different units in fractals and phase transitions, while here we are talking about electrodynamics.

Comment: Gaussian units are nonstandard?

Comment: I think you have differentiate between fractional unit powers and irrational exponents.

Comment: @ja72 Well, I never encountered irrational exponents in units and I'm not aware of any units system that allows that.

Comment: @KyleKanos that depends on the definition of _standard_, what I am saying is that I don't think this situation is possible with SI units.

Comment: Only with "blind" curve fitting you end up with fractional exponents. So the _OP_ should clarify that non-integer means rational only.

Comment: Shouldn't units be in upright font?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis feel free to edit.

Comment: I am not sure whether it will help, but if I am to measure lengths in units of $L^{1/3}$ ($L$ being litre), I measure lengths in non-integer powers of a physical unit ...

Comment: @Tony Indeed litre is not a SI unit.

Comment: For what its worth, the structure constant in Kolmogorov turbulence is measured in m$^{-3/2}$. This is defined in terms of the SI units and it has a physical meaning.

Comment: Your chances to reopen can be significantly improved if you make the distinction clear already in the title of your question. Although I still think that your question and the dupe are essentially the same.

Comment: @peterh they are obviously closely related questions, but if you read them closely they are talking about a different subject, but the most important difference is that there is not a satisfying answer so it's not true that my question has already an answer elsewhere.